# Jordan form and its elements

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused by the following question...

> Find a matrix $A \in R^{3\times3}$, such that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(\lambda - 1)^2(\lambda + 2)$ and $\forall p,q \in \left\{ 1, 2, 3 \right\}$, $[A]_{pq} \in Z - \left\{0\right\}$ and $|[A]_{pq}| \leq 5$

The first thought that came to me is *to construct the dot diagram by the minimal polynomial* then write down the *Jordan canoncial form*, like this
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & * & * \\ 
1 & 1 & * \\
* & * & -2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

In my opinion, it should fill $0$ to those $*$; however, I don't know how to fill in with other integers.

Comment: I think your second term should be $(\lambda+2)$ and not $(\lambda - 1)$.

Comment: I changed $3x3$ to $3\times 3$.  That is standard TeX usage.

Comment: I caught Calvin's suggested edit.

Answer (score 1):

Filling in the $\ast$ with $0$'s will give you the Jordan normal form of the matrix you're looking for.  Then you just need to conjugate it (which does not change the minimal polynomial) into a matrix with the non-zero entries that you want.  For example, conjugating by

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1\\0&1&-1\\1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

does the trick.

Comment: Thanks! But I have no idea what *conjugate* means...Find its conjugate transpose or what?

Comment: If $A$ is invertable then we way that $ABA^{-1}$ is the matrix $B$ conjugated by $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get an example regardless of what entry you wish in the $3,3$ position (and its negative in the linear factor of the characteristic polynomial) is to write down the Jordan Canonical Form including $0$ where you have your stars. That is set
$$ \mathbf{J}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
(or $1$ in the $3,3$ slot if you replace the last factor $(\lambda -1)$  in the characteristic polynomial by $(\lambda -2)$.

Now all you have to do is produce a nice $3\times 3$ matrix with integer entries that has an inverse with integer entries.  I picked $$ \mathbf {P} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 3 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
and computed $\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{JP}$.  No good--zeros in the last column. Pick another matrix $\mathbf{P_1}$ and compute $(\mathbf{PP_1})^{-1}\mathbf{JPP_1}$. Bingo! 
\begin{bmatrix} 
7 & 9 & -18 \\ 
-24 & -29 & 54 \\
-10 & -12 & 22 \\ \end{bmatrix}
works (unless I copied it wrong from my CAS). And it took much less time then writing this.  Now for you--why did it work and how did I know the inverse of $\mathbf{P}$ would have all integer entries?

Comment: Thanks! You're right! I do curious how you pick $P$ and the inverse of it.

Comment: Any integer matrix can be diagonalized by elementary row  and column operations with entries in $\mathbf Z$ using the Euclidean algorithm. That is how the basis theorem for f.g. modules over a Euclidean domain is derived. The product of those entries is the determinant since all the elementary row operations have determinant 1. So P would have inverse with all integral entries iff it has determinant 1, and the best way to do that for me was to make P  block lower triangular to eliminate 0 in the bottom row. Repeating with an upper block triangular matrix to clear the 3rd column. Use CAS.

Comment: By the way, I missed the requirement about values less than 5.